# fmt.Printf() format specifier to print pointer to a struct in its default format?

Tags: pointers, go, struct, format-specifiers

My Go code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Point struct {
    x int
    y int
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(&Point{1, 2})
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", &Point{1, 2})
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", &Point{1, 2})
}
```

Output:

```
&{1 2}
&{1 2}
0xc00002c070
```

This does not match the documentation in https://godoc.org/fmt. The documentation says,

> The default format for %v is:
>
> ```
> bool:                    %t
> int, int8 etc.:          %d
> uint, uint8 etc.:        %d, %#x if printed with %#v
> float32, complex64, etc: %g
> string:                  %s
> chan:                    %p
> pointer:                 %p
> ```

As per the documentation above, for pointers, using `%v` should behave like using `%p`.

Why then does the output of `fmt.Printf("%v\n", &Point{1, 2})` not match the output of `fmt.Printf("%p\n", &Point{1, 2})`?

Comment: Your example code shows you used `%v` and you got identical output. What's the question?

Comment: @icza Updated the question. The output of my program contradicts the `fmt` documentation. I have provided the link to the documentation and included the relevant excerpt from it to show the contradiction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You quoted some part form the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package doc, just not "enough". The continuation of your quote:

> For compound objects, the elements are printed using these rules, recursively, laid out like this:
>
> ```
> struct:             {field0 field1 ...}
> array, slice:       [elem0 elem1 ...]
> maps:               map[key1:value1 key2:value2 ...]
> pointer to above:   &{}, &[], &map[]
> ```

`*Point` is a pointer to struct, thus it is printed using `&{field0 field1 ...}`.

Pointer to struct is very common in Go, and most of the time when printing it you're not interested in the pointer value but the pointed struct (or the pointed struct's fields). So the `fmt` package has a rule to print what most would like to see. If you do need the address, you can print it using `%p` as in your example.